# MySQL Flip data like Cross Tab

Tags: mysql, crosstab

I have the following address data:

```
ID     Address
---------------
1      123 Riverside Drive
1      Pleasantvile
1      Some Country
2      96 Another Street
2      Europe
```

Is there a SQL hack or an easy way to flip this data, based on ID, so that I have the following result spread out into several address fields:

```
ID     Address1             Address2        Address3
----------------------------------------------------------
1      123 Riverside Drive  Pleasantvile    Some Country
2      96 Another Street    Europe
```

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way is to create another table to populate with a query.

Comment: Must you do this in the database layer of your application?  Can't you do it within the presentation layer?

Comment: it's the query to populate another table that I'm not sure of.  Yes, it must be done in the database - there is no application.  Can't think of a way to flip the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the number of addresses per id before hand

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = ', rnum,
                           ' THEN address END) `address', rnum, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM 
(
  SELECT id, address, @n := IF(@g = id, @n + 1, 1) rnum, @g := id
    FROM table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @g := NULL) i
   ORDER BY id, address
) q;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id,', @sql,
                  '  FROM 
                  (
                    SELECT id, address, @n := IF(@g = id, @n + 1, 1) rnum, @g := id
                      FROM table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @g := NULL) i
                     ORDER BY id, address
                  ) q
                   GROUP BY id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e845b/7)**  demo

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the number of rows for every address are at maximum three, you could use a hack like this:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Rownum=1 THEN Address END) As Address1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Rownum=2 THEN Address END) As Address2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Rownum=3 THEN Address END) As Address3
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    @row:=CASE WHEN @lastid=id THEN @row+1 ELSE 1 END AS Rownum,
    Address,
    @lastid:=id
  FROM
    addresses
  ORDER BY
    id, Address
  ) s
GROUP BY
  ID
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de1bd/2).